# Automatically create a large matrix from smaller matrices in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I have a number of smaller matrices that I would like to combine into a larger matrix.

I am attempting to do this with the `hstack` command in Numpy but it treats each combination as a string and not by the matrices that the string represents. The `hstack` command works fine if I manually code it.

```
import numpy as np 
import itertools as it 

sm01 = np.matrix( [[1],[1],[1]] ) 
sm02 = np.matrix( [[2],[2],[2]] )   
sm03 = np.matrix( [[3],[3],[3]] )   

Variables = ['sm01','sm02','sm03']
Comblst = ['']
for i in range(0, len(Variables)+1):
  for subset in it.combinations(Variables, i):
    a = str(subset).strip('()')
    Comblst = np.vstack([Comblst,a])

var = str(Comblst[6]).strip('[]').strip('""').strip(',').replace("'","")
var = tuple(var.split(', '))
LargeMatrix = np.hstack([var])
```

Comment: Add a sample case?

Comment: We need to see actual, runnable code that actually demonstrates the problem when run.

Comment: the code is too long to add

Comment: Show us shorter, simplified code. It just needs to be actually valid Python and actually demonstrate the problem. What you've posted is useless.

Comment: thanks! I have posted simplified code

Answer (score 0):

I think you should build `Conblst` with list append, not `vstack`.

```
Comblst = []
for
    for 
        Comblst.append(a)
```

Show us what `Comblst` and `var` look like.  I can't follow the construction by just reading the code.

And what's the result of the `hstack`.

====================

```
Out[1087]: ['sm01', 'sm02', 'sm03']
In [1088]: Comblst
Out[1088]: 
array([[''],
       [''],
       ["'sm01',"],
       ["'sm02',"],
       ["'sm03',"],
       ["'sm01', 'sm02'"],
       ["'sm01', 'sm03'"],
       ["'sm02', 'sm03'"],
       ["'sm01', 'sm02', 'sm03'"]], 
      dtype='<U22')

In [1090]: var = str(Comblst[6]).strip('[]').strip('""').strip(',').replace("'",
      ...: "")
      ...: var = tuple(var.split(', '))
      ...: 
In [1091]: var
Out[1091]: ('sm01', 'sm03')

In [1092]: np.hstack([var])
Out[1092]: 
array(['sm01', 'sm03'], 
      dtype='<U4')
```

This is just a bunch of string manipulations, which would be better done with lists rather than arrays.  But what's the purpose?  Are you actually aiming to produce

```
In [1093]: np.hstack([sm01, sm03])
Out[1093]: 
matrix([[1, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 3]])
```

In Python there is a very real difference between strings or names, and the objects they reference.

I suspect a better of way of building `Comblst` is:

```
In [1096]: 
      ...: Comblst = []
      ...: for i in range(0, len(Variables)+1):
      ...:   for subset in itertools.combinations(Variables, i):
      ...:     # a = str(subset).strip('()')
      ...:     Comblst.append(subset)
      ...:     
      ...:     
In [1097]: Comblst
Out[1097]: 
[(),
 ('sm01',),
 ('sm02',),
 ('sm03',),
 ('sm01', 'sm02'),
 ('sm01', 'sm03'),
 ('sm02', 'sm03'),
 ('sm01', 'sm02', 'sm03')]

In [1099]: Comblst[5]
Out[1099]: ('sm01', 'sm03')
```

Forget about making and splitting strings; instead just collect tuples of these names.

But you don't have to work with the names; you can start with a list of the matrices themselves:

```
In [1101]: Mlist=[sm01, sm02, sm03]
In [1102]: 
      ...: Comblst = []
      ...: for i in range(0, len(Mlist)+1):
      ...:   for subset in itertools.combinations(Mlist, i):
      ...:     Comblst.append(subset)
      ...:     
In [1103]: Comblst
Out[1103]: 
[(), (matrix([[1],
          [1],
          [1]]),), (matrix([[2],
          [2],
          [2]]),), (matrix([[3],
          [3],
          ....
          [3]]))]
In [1104]: Comblst[5]
Out[1104]: 
(matrix([[1],
         [1],
         [1]]), matrix([[3],
         [3],
         [3]]))
In [1105]: np.hstack(Comblst[5])
Out[1105]: 
matrix([[1, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 3]])
```

Or construct a list of simple numeric tuples, and index with that

```
In [1109]: 
      ...: Comblst = []
      ...: for i in range(0, len(Mlist)+1):
      ...:   for subset in itertools.combinations( list(range(0, len(Mlist))), i):
      ...:     Comblst.append(subset)

In [1110]: Comblst
Out[1110]: [(), (0,), (1,), (2,), (0, 1), (0, 2), (1, 2), (0, 1, 2)]
In [1111]: Comblst[5]
Out[1111]: (0, 2)
In [1112]: np.hstack([Mlist[i] for i in Comblst[5]])
Out[1112]: 
matrix([[1, 3],
        [1, 3],
        [1, 3]])
```